# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath' in flutter

Tags: flutter

Yesterday i woke up and found my Visual studio misbehaving. I had to delete all my file in .graddle folder and then re-download them but it's giving the errors below, i have tried googling for solutions but all in vain.
I am using Graddle:
gradle-6.7-all.zip
I am using linux mint distro.

```
-Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug
[+454406 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +7 ms] * What went wrong:
[   +1 ms] A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
[   +1 ms] > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
[   +2 ms]    > Could not download builder-4.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0)
[   +1 ms]       > Could not get resource
'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/4.1.0/builder-4.1.0.jar'.
[   +9 ms]          > Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 9,546,513; received: 4,456,416)
[   +2 ms]    > Could not download kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.50.jar
(org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.50)
[  +11 ms]       > Could not get resource
'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.3.50/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.50.jar'.
[   +4 ms]          > Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 36,615,572; received: 4,456,416)
[   +1 ms]    > Could not download fastutil-7.2.0.jar (it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:7.2.0)
[   +2 ms]       > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.2.0/fastutil-7.2.0.jar'.
[   +5 ms]          > Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 17,309,408; received: 6,553,552)
[   +2 ms] * Try:
[   +2 ms] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run
with --scan to get full insights.
[   +3 ms] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[   +1 ms] BUILD FAILED in 7m 33s
[ +627 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 455.5s)
[  +10 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[   +4 ms] "flutter run" took 461,160ms.
[  +14 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:644:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1157:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1009:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:278:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:234:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #12     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #14     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #15     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:73:10)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #16     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           
           
[ +260 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 252ms
[   +3 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hook priority 4
[  +14 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +1 ms] exiting with code 1
```